# Is there a way to instantiate a CanvasRenderingContext2D object without the document for use in a web worker?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, canvas, web-worker

Here's what I know how to do:

```
var buffer=document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
var buffer=CanvasRenderingContext2D();
```

Is this possible? Is there a way to create a CanvasRenderingContext2D object without the document's `createElement` method?

The reason I'd like to know is because I'm working with web workers, and I'd like to see if I can move some of the drawing to a worker. The drawing operations would stay in the separate thread and the final rendering to the display canvas would be done in the main document thread. I'm also not sure if that's possible.

If anyone has any information on either of these topics (web workers and drawing or ways to instantiate CanvasRenderingContext2D), please let me know!

Thanks!

Edit:

For reference, the context of my project is creating a game loop. I've noticed that drawing is pretty much my most cpu intensive task, eating a whopping 10% of my cpu according to profiles done with Chrome dev tools. If there were some way of doing all the image buffering on the web worker and then passing a rendering context (or something) back to the main document thread to do the final drawing to the display canvas, it would be a huge load off of the main thread, which would handle input and repeated calls to `requestAnimationFrame`, which would handle the final drawing to the "canvas" element.

Now, I'm not sure if this is possible, like I said before, but I've looked at a lot of tutorials that say web workers are great for image editing applications (although none of them go into detail). Maybe this is referring to filter functions that loop over every pixel in the image and perform a cpu intensive filter function, but really, if those functions have access to the image data array, then why wouldn't I be able to access the image for basic drawing operations in the same web worker?

Anyway, that's the context of the project: creating a game loop that can handle buffering images in a web worker so the main thread can focus on updating the display "canvas" element and collecting user input.

Comment: If you want to draw lines and use the 2d context methods, I don´t know, but if are drawing images (using the ArrayBuffer with rgba), you could communicate with the worker using that array...

Comment: Even if you could create an isolated context in the worker, you wouldn’t be able to pass it back; so that kind of parallel rendering doesn’t seem possible. Most of the time, however, you actually can organise the task with ArrayBuffer mentioned above. Knowing the specifics of the use case might help.

Comment: I added some specifics. I do plan on using transferable objects or an ArrayBuffer object to send, rather than clone, between threads for faster sharing. But the documents I read were pretty adamant that web workers don't have access to the DOM... Not sure if this means direct access or no access, but I didn't see anything about being able to pass element objects between threads, so my guess is you can't.

Comment: When they say web workers are great for image editing applications, they mean something like what Juan Pablo wrote above: you take ArrayBuffer with `getImageData()` and go from there. But as far as I understand, that’s not what you want; you want to actually use drawing API in the worker. As per spec, it’s not possible, and I doubt reimplementing Canvas yourself (as proposed below) would help with performance in any way. WebGL would, but that’s another story.

Comment: @KlimLee. Actually, I was trying to make reimplimenting `CanvasRenderingContext2D` sound too formidable to be worthwhile(!). Later in my answer I do suggest the "more usual" way of marshalling data to the worker for processing. ;-)

Comment: @markE, That wasn’t meant to criticise you. Your answer is technically correct, and reimplementing APIs could actually be a viable option. You just didn’t mention that reimplementation would almost inevitably slow down the computation (and the very reason for using workers here was performance gain).

Comment: @KlimLee. All good here! Yes, reimplimenting the entire API would be inefficient and a performance reducer.

Comment: I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel, but `getImageData()` sounds promising. I'm not bent on using `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, either. I just need to get the job done faster, the specifics aren't all that important. If there's no good way to do it, I could always keep drawing on the main thread. It's not breaking the CPU, and unlike the logic side, it won't really grow as my project becomes larger, because I'll always be drawing the same sprites regardless of AI and physics. I just thought it'd be nice to have the option.

Answer (score 0):

Web workers do not natively support DOM objects.

So canvas's `CanvasRenderingContext2D` is not natively available inside web workers.

To get `CanvasRenderingContext2D` inside a web worker you must reproduce all of its methods and properties (or at least as many methods and properties that are needed for your app).

This is obviously a large and daunting task.

GitHub's `Automattic Group` has done just that to create html5 canvas support for NodeJS: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/tree/master/src You could use this as a starting point and convert needed portions of it to javascript. It is still a large and daunting task.

But there is still more work to do...

After you've recreated the required methods and properties and done your work on the worker, you must still marshall the CanvasRenderingContext2D properties back to the main thread. You must also marshall the pixel data that your web-worker-rendering-context has drawn back to the main thread.

I don't know of anyone whose done the code for this. It's more common to:

- Marshall data from the main thread to workers.
- Use code in the worker to create your desired data.
- Marshall data from the worker back to the main thread.

Comment: I don't think I'm up to the task of recreating `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Besides, I doubt it'd be as fast as the native code. I may just have to accept the limitation.

Comment: Yep, probably recreating the whole API is not useful. But keep in mind that recreating **only part of the API** is often done in web workers. For example, you might want to apply a grayscale filter to the canvas. You would marshall the pixel data to the web worker and the web worker would manipulate the pixel data using the same methods you would use directly on the canvas. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks, markE. My problem is that I'm super new to web workers. Once I get one running, I'll be able to tinker with it. I think I'm going to look into using image data. Maybe that'll yield some results.

Comment: Here's a fairly good tutorial on using web workers with html canvas: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/using-web-workers-to-improve-performance-of-image-manipulation.html#fbid=-CNKN-Azjyw